# Convert PDF to html using Adobe Api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

Is it possible to covert PDF file  to html file using purely JavaScript or jQuery with Adobe JavaScript Api?

Is there a free Api to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you understand "Adobe JavaScript Api" as "Acrobat JavaScript API", then the answer is definitely No.

Adobe has other JavaScript APIs, such as ExtendScript (used in Photoshop, InDesign, Illustrator etc.). The answer is still No.

You might find something in the webbrowser environment, which may be able to do some conversions.

Comment: Why no? Adobe Acrobat can save into HTML using Javascript, can it not?